# Using search option from ajax request

Tags: html, ajax

I have a HTML page where there are displayed results. The results are displayed in a table which is called with ajax as shown in below code.

How can i create a search box where user would input a name and then the table would change so only results with that name are shown:

Example

my table looks like this on html site:

Position:
Name:

1 
audi

2
bmw

3
audi x

Now i want there to be a search box:

Type name: AUDI <--- user types that

and now table should be

Position:
Name:

1 
audi

3
audi x

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
setInterval(function() {
$('#results').load('branje_sablon.php');
}, 3000); 
});
</script>
<div id="results"></div>
```

edit:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.css"> 
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
$(document).ready( function () {
$('#results').DataTable('branje_sablon.php');
} );

</script>
<div id="results">Loading data ...</div>
```

Comment: please use jquery dataTables this is plugin of jquery for achive same functionality  you like https://datatables.net/

Comment: Can you checked my edit? SO like this? Really new to Jquery and php so a little help would be appritiated

Comment: why are you passing ** $('#results').DataTable('branje_sablon.php'); ** Use like $('#results').DataTable();

Comment: ok but how am i gettting data from branje_sablon.php? On that site i am reading and using echo for my table

Comment: $(document).ready(function() {
$.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 
setInterval(function() {
$('#results').load('branje_sablon.php');
}, 3000); 
$('#results').DataTable();
});

Comment: add this only in script

Comment: still getting no data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120959/discussion-between-jan-and-junaid-ahmed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 

    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false }); 

         setTimeout(function() { 

         $('#mainResults').load('branje_sablon.php'); 

         setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('#mainResults').DataTable(); 
            },1000);

        }, 1000); 

    });
```